# How to get a subactivity to extend MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, extend, mapactivity, subactivity

So I have a `MainActivity` and a `SubActivity` and I want the `SubActivity` to extend a `MapActivity`. But the program would not let me do this. It says that `MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type`. How can I get the SubActivity to extend MapActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Check your build path, you need the Google APIs, it contains the "maps.jar" you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Google Map API` is a separate SDK. Choose it in packages manager or set your project's build target to Google API.